# Python create function with parameter names based on other function arguments

Tags: python, parameters, dynamic-function

In python 3.x is there any way to create a dynamic fuction (inner) with parameter names that are based on arguments passed to the other function (outer). Something like this:

```
def outer(x = {'alpha': 1, 'lambda_': 2}):
    # do something to receive the following function definition:
    def inner(alpha, lambda_):
        # do something
        return something_inner
    return something_outer
```

Here, by passing some dictionary as an argument to x I want to create a definition of inner function that will take alpha and lambda_ as arguments. If I pass  x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2} I want my inner function to have parameter names of a and b: def inner(a, b): ...
Is there any soluton to this?

Comment: When you're writing the code, you can't use `alpha` or `lambda_` because you don't know that those are the names passed in.  It might make more sense for your inner to accept `(*args, **kwargs)` and then have logic inside it to confirm that it got all the required arguments

Comment: def inner(alpha, lambda_) served only as an example and indeed I don't want to write that in my function; what I want to achieve is to dynamically create a function definition that will be changing based on input of outer function; I was thinking about the exec() to do this but I am not sure whether it is the correct way;

Comment: But the whole point of named arguments is so that you can reference them in the actual code of the function.  How will you use the values passed into the function if you don't know their names when you write the code? Could your provide some example code where the `# do something` in `inner` depends on the arguments?

Comment: The whole point of this is the fact that I won't execute this function directly. The function name will be passed to another function (as an argument) that optimises parameters from inner function - in this case alpha and lambda_.